# Nightwatch Page Object hierarchy/re-use

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'd like to use Nightwatch's Page Objects system for UI components used across our app. Because nightwatch has their own way of reading/initializing them, I don't see a way of properly extending/re-using them.

For example I want an `DateInputPageObject` for "date fields". It would identify the label, input, date picker, etc.

I'd use it on any page with a date input field.

I would also like to extend page objects. For example, `class FooModal extends Modal`. The `ModalPageObject` would define selectors for elements all modals have - the overlay, container, close button, etc.

I can't find any way to do this in nightwatch, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with nightwatch per se as it's just following the basic structure of page object model BUT that is a very good question and it brings out one of the drawbacks of page object model.

Page object model has been around for some time and the problem with that is that it doesn't serve the needs of modern web applications that use component libraries & living style-guides and re-using components.

Personally I found it easier to use a global json file with all the components structured based on their type. e.g. labels, fields, buttons, etc.

Comment: But NW definitely gets in the way because in other projects, the POM is more of a plain class structure that could be used in such a way. For example, I do this now with TestCafe. Because NW handles parsing/instantiating them, it's stolen control of that structure.

Comment: NW tries indeed to make it easier to use POM but it's also a limited functionality. You might want to search outside NW structure for this.